# How to create a specific function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a function but not sure how to get started.

At the moment I have an IF statement that I have to keep repeating for many variations on quantity of size within my database.

```
   $size = '43';
// check if size is available 
if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$size.''] > 0 ) { 
?>

<?=$line['product_id']?>, 
<?=$line['code_c_size_'.$size.'']?>,
EAN, 
<?=$line['title']?>, 


<?=preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', ' ', $line['amazon_desc']) ?>,
<?=$size?>,
<?=$line['colour']?>, 

Shoes, 
UPDATE, 
<?=$line['shoe_id']?>, 
<?=$line['price']?>,
<?=$line['price']?>,
GBP,
<?=$line['quantity_c_size_'.$size.'']?>,
A_GEN_NOTAX,
<?=$line['added_y']?>-<?=$line['added_m']?>-<?=$line['added_d']?>,
<?=$line['added_y']?>-<?=$line['added_m']?>-<?=$line['added_d']?>,
?>
```

This repeated for every size within the database -  each 'quantity_size' column is separate within the database.

Here's a list of all possible sizes :

```
'quantity_c_size_42'
'quantity_c_size_425'
'quantity_c_size_43'
'quantity_c_size_435'
'quantity_c_size_44'
'quantity_c_size_445'
'quantity_c_size_45'
'quantity_c_size_455'
'quantity_c_size_46'
'quantity_c_size_465'
'quantity_c_size_47'
'quantity_c_size_475'
'quantity_c_size_48'
'quantity_c_size_485'
'quantity_size_one'
'quantity_size_1'
'quantity_size_2'
'quantity_size_3'
'quantity_size_4'
'quantity_size_5'
'quantity_size_6'
'quantity_size_7'
'quantity_size_8'
'quantity_size_9'
'quantity_size_10'
'quantity_size_11'
'quantity_size_12'
'quantity_size_13'
'quantity_size_15'
'quantity_size_25'
'quantity_size_35'
'quantity_size_45'
'quantity_size_55'
'quantity_size_65'
'quantity_size_75'
'quantity_size_85'
'quantity_size_95'
'quantity_size_105'
'quantity_size_115'
'quantity_size_125'
```

So essentially, I know that I need a function that gets the size and passes this to the IF statement - however, I'm not sure how to implement it.

ELABORATION:

The IF Statement logic is as follows:

IF one of the possible 'quantity_size' column is greater than 0 
Then do ...

So the function needs to check whether any of the possible 'quantity_size' columns has quantity greater than zero and get the size (i.e. 42) within the column name. Rather than having to check for each size individually.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I have NO idea what you're trying to ask here. Elaborate your question.

Comment: so in essence you want a call to a new function to replace this `if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$size.''] > 0 )` so that it will look like `if(getSize($valueWithSize) > 0)`?

Comment: `'quantity_size' column is separate...` - correct me if I'm wrong, but does that mean you have dozens of columns in a single table to store `quantity sizes`?

Comment: @raina77ow - yes at the moment there are dozens of columns all relating to quantity of a particular size.

Answer (score 2):

Hey use switch cases for your every $size by using explode and put it in a switch case and avoid all the if statements.

```
$m= explode("_", $line['quantity_c_size_'.$size.'']);
switch($m){
case 1:......

 case 2:
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more just to I understand as I haven't used explode with a switch statement before...

Comment: See my edited post above - based on the full code could you flesh out your example above? Please

Comment: Am sorry,i muisunderstood the question,if there is a requirement of only one if loop then your code is alright

Comment: There may have been a misunderstanding - as at the moment I am using multiple IF loops for all the possible 'quantity_size' columns. To edit the code requires lots of copy and pasting. It's completely inefficient. Hence why I'm trying to write a function to replace all of the IF loops. thanks

Comment: Hey in case you wish to write multiple if for every quantity ;go for switch statements ;refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php;  switch($variable){ case 1:code;case 2:code....similarly

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
<?php
    function getSize($string){
        $array = explode ( "_", $string);
        return $array[count($array) - 1];
    }
    $size = getSize("quantity_size_10");
    switch($size){
    case ...:
        .
        . 
    break;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSize($size) {
  if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$size.''] > 0 ) {
    // Run code
  }
}
getSize(75);
```

Is this what you are looking for?